# Edge coloring hierarchy

Tags: color, bevel

my problem is when I'm doing complex project for some game I have to do few things in one edge which is mostly: edge sharp, edge seam and edge bevel weight, sometime after check all sharp edges i'm doing bevel and seams at the same time but blender is showing only one color (blender hierarchy is: 1. Seams [red] 2. Bevel weight [dark blue] 3. Sharp edges [light blue]) and It would be really helpfull to be able to change that hierarchy for like few hours and than change again. Been looking for that setting in properties but found only option for changing a color for one operation.

Best regards

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can change the hierarchy. Best option is probably to turn the display of each overlay edge type on and off by adding it to the quick menu.

Comment: @JohnEason this is actually a perfect sollution thanks a lot for help!

Comment: No problem. I'll rustle up an answer with images shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the hierarchy, but you can add the option to turn the display on and off on the quick menu.
[image]

1. Bring up the overlay menu.
2. Right-click on a display option (in this case Sharp) and
3. Select Add to Quick favorites.

I'm using Hardops, hence all the menu entries shown below, but normally pressing Q will just bring up the quick menu and you can turn the displays on and off from there.
[image]